# How to add the source packages on launchpad to my PPA?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, source-packages

I have a working project on launchpad, with generation of packages for three version of Ubuntu distribution and all is fine there. However, I cannot find the option to tell launchpad to put the source package on my PPA for people to download. I would like my users to be able to do:

```
$ apt-get source my-package
```

And get the source package that they can compile on their own machine if they want to.

Is it possible to make the source package available from my PPA?

Just in case, here is my project: https://code.launchpad.net/~pierre-barbierdereuille/lithographx/main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just point your package users to add PPA with source option:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -s ppa:pierre-barbierdereuille/ppa
```

instead of binary builds only:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pierre-barbierdereuille/ppa
```

**Reference:** [`man add-apt-repository`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html)

> **-s**,  **--enable-source**  Allow downloading of the source packages from the repository

Comment: Thank you! I just thought the sources would be available by default!