# How do I specify build-dep command to grab git version 2.10

Tags: 14.04, git

I have an issue where I need to execute the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep git
mkdir ~/git-openssl
cd ~/git-openssl
apt-get source git
dpkg-source -x git_1.7.9.5-1.dsc
cd git-1.7.9.5
```

For my Ubuntu 14.04 installation I upgraded git to version 2.10.2 but when I get to this step (`sudo apt-get build-dep git`) the git package version is 1.9.1. My question is simple. Is there a way to use the `build-dep` command to get version 2.10.2?

Comment: Never seen build-dep return what version of source it's getting the build dependencies  for. If you installed git-2.10 as a proper debian package then apt-get build-dep would base off of that. If not then it would base off of the current 14.04 package (1.9.1)

Comment: Not to discourage custom building, but if you're just using the release as is without modification, then there's a great ppa for the latest `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the latest ppa with the `--enable-source` flag ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/640485/774721)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository --enable-source ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

You can find my fork of the full script I used on my Ubuntu 14.04 server [here](https://gist.github.com/mrexodia/8aa3cc4e42a48f73768ac7465d5b1465):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Clear out all previous attempts
rm -rf "/tmp/source-git/"

# Add PPA for latest git
sudo add-apt-repository --enable-source ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update

# Get the dependencies for git, then get openssl
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev -y
sudo apt-get build-dep git -y
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev -y
mkdir -p "/tmp/source-git/"
cd "/tmp/source-git/"
apt-get source git

# We need to actually go into the git source directory
# find -type f -name "*.dsc" -exec dpkg-source -x \{\} \;
cd $(find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "git-*")
pwd

# This is where we actually change the library from one type to the other.
sed -i -- 's/libcurl4-gnutls-dev/libcurl4-openssl-dev/' ./debian/control
# Compile time, itself, is long. Skips the tests. Do so at your own peril.
sed -i -- '/TEST\s*=\s*test/d' ./debian/rules

# Build it.
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -uc -us

# Install
find .. -type f -name "git_*ubuntu*.deb" -exec sudo dpkg -i \{\} \;
```

I had previously installed `git` so the last command gave me an error about missing dependencies with `liberror-perl`, the following fixed it for me

```
sudo apt-get install liberror-perl
sudo apt-get -f install
find .. -type f -name "git_*ubuntu*.deb" -exec sudo dpkg -i \{\} \;
```